# Proper entry of Konami Code?

Tags: cheats, contra

1. I start Contra.
2. I start playing the first level.
3. up-up-down-down-left-right-left-right-B-A-Start.
4. Nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Some games use Select instead of Start.

Comment: @MatthewRead: Contra uses Select before Start only if you're playing a two player game.

Answer (score 7):

The Konami Code should be entered in the main menu, not in a level.

Answer (score 1):

[Most games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Konami_code_games) using the [Konami code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konami_Code) will have the player input it on the title screen.

In the case of *Contra*, go to the title screen and then enter the code. Push <kbd>Select</kbd> before pushing <kbd>Start</kbd> to start the game in 2-player mode with 30 lives each.